# como conectar login session con aws api Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aws

quisiera poder escribir algo de codigo pero no se ni como empezarlo, por eso cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Tengo que crear un login session (2 EditText, email and password, y un Boton para validar) con una api aws, busque mucho pero no entiendo, y no me queda claro como hacerlo.

conocen algun tutorial claro como hacer esto? tienen algun tipo de codigo?
NO PIDO QUE LO HAGAN POR MI, simplemente necesito saber como empezarlo, razonarlo, porque nose ni como empezar, es mi primera vez con AWS conectando con android, y no entiendo las explicaciones de la documentacion oficial, no logro entenderlo.
Desde ya muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Recuerda realizar tus preguntas agregando lo que trataste o investigaste (ver [ask]), en este caso puedes obtener reputación para realizar este tipo de consultas en [chat], ahí hay varios miembros de la comunidad que te pueden ayudar,revisa https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/User-Sign-in.html  saludos.

Comment: muchisimas gracias @Jorgesys por tu tiempo y buena onda, intente este link que me pasas, y mi situacion es la siguiente, comprendo todo, y entiendo como hacer el setting de dependencias y todo, pero yo cuento con una API de aws y en ningun lado.. puedo ver como utilizar ese API.necesito comprender esa parte de codigo para poder seguir.. de todas formas agradezco tu tiempo y buena onda

Comment: @Jorgesys te puedo encontrar en alguno de estos chats en particular?

Comment: Si, en [chat] pero debes obtener reputaciòn minimo de 50 para ingresar.

Comment: ohh comprendo, claro, estoy lejos aun.. @Jorgesys pero entendes mi pregunta? no subi codigo porque nose ni como empezar, veo mucho codigo en la documentacion y no entiendo aun que hacer... generar un login session.. (email and password) para ello se me dio un aws API gateway .. ni idea como hacerlo y no encuentro nada que me aclare esas dudas..la documenacion no muestra como implementar o usar esa api en mi codigo en android studio.. o
es que debo utlizar esa API en la consola de aws?eso no logro comprender..si utlizo esa aws API en mi android studio o en la consola de aws, ojala me entiendas